# Get multiple values in URL encoding

Tags: api, url, tumblr

I'm not sure how to go about searching this but I'm trying to read the tumblr API and get all posts of type=audio OR type=photo, so I only want to see audio and photo posts.

This doesn't work:
http://derekg.org/api/read?&type=audio&type=photo

it only retrieves type=photo posts. What is the syntax for type=photo OR audio?

Comment: Have you tried `http://derekg.org/api/read?type=audio,photo`?

Comment: yes, that just gets all posts with type="audio,photo" which is none because "audio,photo" is not a valid type

Comment: Look at the total with no type it is 1344, but with `audio,photo` it is 276.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1#api_read

> `type` - The type of posts to return. If unspecified or empty, all types
>   of posts are returned. Must be one of text, quote, photo, link, chat,
>   video, or audio.

I would assume the way to get multiple categories is using a comma.

http://derekg.org/api/read?type=audio,photo

The difference is in the total post count. With no type it is 1344, but with `audio,photo` it is 276.

Your current url (http://derekg.org/api/read?&type=audio&type=photo) is just overriding the audio parameter.

Otherwise, you are going to have to do two calls; one `photo` and one `audio`. Then merge and sort them however you choose. This answer may also help: [How to query multiple tags in Tumblr's read api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043119/how-to-query-multiple-tags-in-tumblrs-read-api)

Comment: Yes, with type `audio,photo` it returns fewer posts but if you actually look at the `type` it's `type="regular"` which is NOT the same. I'm not really sure what kind of posts it's returning.

Comment: You'll have to do multiple calls then I'm afraid.

Comment: Sadly what @SamV is correct, you can only query one media type at a time. The docs back this up: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts